# Ruby can not require mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

On Mac OS X 10.9.2, I use this command line on terminal to install mysql lib for Ruby:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install mysql2
```

And it shows:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.15
Parsing documentation for mysql2-0.3.15
Done installing documentation for mysql2 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But I still can not use:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'
```

It shows :

```
in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql (LoadError)
```

What should I do next?

Comment: you installed the `mysql2` gem - should you be requiring mysql2 instead?

Comment: I think you need to install `mysql` gem it will solve as you did require mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed the 'mysql2' gem. You need to require that gem within your code:

```
require 'mysql2'
```

Then everything should work just fine.